# WPML config file

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I'm trying to add wpml-config.xml in root directory of my theme. File has only one option:

```
<wpml-config>
    <custom-field action="translate">block_1</custom-field>
</wpml-config>
```

[image]

But no mater what I do options are not checked in Translation management (check image above). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's missing the main option key. It should be:

```
<wpml-config>
    <custom-fields> 
        <custom-field action="translate">block_1</custom-field>
    </custom-fields>
</wpml-config>
```

More info about **WPML Language Configuration Files** here:

http://wpml.org/documentation/support/language-configuration-files/

Comment: Omg I didn't noticed that little thing. Thanks so much